# Android tablet USB Host mode yes or no?

Tags: android, usb, host

I trying to make a android App, that uses an usb device that need the tablet to be in HOST mode, so it can get power from the tablet. For some odd reason, this only happens every other time I restart the tablet and only if I have the power jack inserted.

So The solution I'm trying to make, is to find out after a reboot if the tablet is in USB Host mode and if not, then reboot automatically.

The tablets are rooted, so superadmin access is no problem and my reboot code is working fine, just can't seem to find anything that says how I can detect Host mode, can anyone share this knowledge with me?

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: Is the device plugged in to USB when you try to detect?

Comment: It is always pluggedin, but only every second time the tablet restarts, does it get power, so I would like to test if the tablet is in USB Host mode, which is what I'm not sure how to do?

Comment: Okay after testing a lot and getting a technician involved, it seems that the problem is that on some restarts the USB Device Reset fails, can anyone tell me, if there is a command in Android to reset USB device manually??

Answer (score 0):

`releaseInterface()` and `close()` closes the connection and stuff. I think then you should be able to `getDeviceList()` or soemthing. 
I can't be too sure, since I used slickdev library to connect to my serial device, but this answer is based on data of this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html